# DropDownList SelectList in ViewBag or View Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, viewbag

Do most developers put their `SelectList` objects in the stongly typed view model or in `ViewBag`?

Initially I used the view model as much as possible but now it doesn't make sense to store some stuff in the view model. A `SelectList` called "Items" could conflict with an actual `DBSet<Item>` called "Items". I'm already using `ViewBag` for the page title and there's no way I'm putting a `Title` property in every one of my view models.

Another problem is I need to manually configure AutoMapper to ignore the `SelectList` properties from every view model and I need to exclude them in `BindAttribute` as well.

If I start using `ViewBag` for `SelectList`s exclusively there might be instances where I'm forced to use the view model for a `SelectList` such as for a drop down in a row in a table where the items are specific to the row. What do you think?

Comment: styles vary. I usually find myself using ViewBag for SelectList. I cast it before use. Many others will swear by Model. I prefer to save the model for model binding. You will find you are better off NOT naming the bound value and select list the same. In some cases that stops a helper from initializing incoming values correctly.

Comment: I updated my question with some more concerns.

Comment: AutoMapper is a great reason to lean on ViewBag. There may in fact be instances where you are better served using a Model for your SelectList. I'm partial to using ViewBag but at times I go the Model way. All your thoughts are on and the answer will depend on the situation. And, at times, it will be a tough decision. For all the reasons you mentioned. That's why I have a preference but don't believe in a rule.

Comment: (1) _" there's no way I'm putting a Title property in every one of my view models"_ - Use a ViewModelBase class with a `Title` property in the same way you should have ` ControllerBase` class for common code. (2) _" I need to exclude them in BindAttribute as well"_ - why? - your `SelectList` items don't post back (unless you have done something silly like rendered hidden inputs for each property of each `SelectListItem`)